# REST API calls through Pentaho Data Integration (Spoon)

Tags: rest, pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

Hello Pentaho Experts,

I am attempting to make a REST API call through REST Client in Pentaho. I have a Api key for authentication. I tried it in Postman, and it works perfectly fine, but Pentaho throws 403 status code. Below is the postman screenshot:

[image]

My Pentaho transformation contains two steps. I am passing URL through "Generate Rows" step and then adding Key and Value in the Header:

**Generate Rows:**
[image]

**Rest Client (General):**

[image]

**Rest Client (Header):**

[image]

Any idea what I might be missing here? Expected output is JSON.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't speak to the use of passing key/value in Header for authentication, but what has worked for me is to use the Authentication tab to input my credentials or passing an Authentication header with a bearer token.

**Authentication Tab**:
I use this method to generate and return a bearer token from the API. The token is then used as the authentication method in subsequent steps. The "body" includes the scope (i.e.: "reports:read") and grant type ("client_credentials"). The "header" contains the value "application/x-www-form-urlencoded".
[image: Generate Rows]
[image: Script body]
[image: REST client General]

[image: REST client Authentication]

[image: REST client Header]

**Authentication Header**:
Once a token has been returned from the API, this can be provided in an "authorization" header. Prepend "bearer" to the token value and pass this in the header tab.
[image: java script to build authorization header]
[image: REST client General token]

[image: REST client Headers token]

I would also recommend looking at the Headers being passed in Postman to ensure you are not missing anything else that might be happening in your call.